# Possible to refer to a C++ array type without a name?

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax

I've been asking myself a very simple C++ question, but can't seem to find a definitive answer. Is it possible to refer to the type of a C++ array without giving it a name? Obviously I'm talking about sized arrays here, not pointers!

For instance imagine the following, where `ARRAY_T_N` is the type of a plain array of `n` elements of `T`:

```
template<class T, int n, bool useStd>
struct array :
    std::conditional<useStd, std::array<T,n>, ARRAY_T_N>
    {};
```

I can use a simple template to define `ARRAY_T_N`:

```
template<class T, int n> struct array_t {
    typedef T type[n];
};
// ARRAY_T_N is array_y<T,n>::type
```

But I wonder if there is a syntax to express this type natively in C++ ?

---

Another way to look at this is that generally, types can either be bound to a name:

```
BoundType variable; // variable declaration or function parameter
typedef BoundType  type_alias; // type aliasing
```

or, they can be used anonymously:

```
some_template<AnonType>  // template instantiation
using type_alias = AnonType; // C++11 type aliasing
```

In most of the cases, for a given type, both forms `BoundType` and `AnonType` are exactly the same, as in `int* ptr` and `std::vector<int*>`.

But sometimes things work differently, as for function pointers: `int (*fptr)(int)` and `std::vector<int(*)(int)>` -- here the `BoundType` and `AnonType` have different syntax for the same type (you can't write, say, `int(*)(int) fptr`)

In the case of plain arrays, does C++ define an `AnonType` syntax?

Comment: Does `T[N]` not do what you want?

Comment: Well I tried it and it didn't compile. But now in a simpler example it does... I'm going to check what's going on

Comment: Yeah definitely a problem with my code -- sorry for this question ;)

Comment: Haha okay just checking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use an array type directly without typedef or type alias, for example:

```
std::unique_ptr< int[6] > smart;
```

Comment: Not every place allows the full declarator syntax. For example it doesn't work with the syntax for creating a temporary of a particular type: `int[6]{1,2,3,4,5,6}`. There you do need a typedef (and if you can't use `std::array` the best option is a `using` template alias: `template<typename T, int N> using raw_array = T[N];` `raw_array<int,6>{1,2,3,4,5,6}`)

Comment: @barnes doesn't that limitation apply with multi token primitives types too, such as unsigned long long?

Comment: Yep. Just something to keep in mind when one finds that the seemingly obvious type syntax isn't working as one expects.